# Axios post isn't handling the response

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, axios

I am uploading images to Cloudinary and want to retrieve the image url after it is uploaded. It is uploading correctly and I can console.log the url on server side but afterwards the response is not handled in the axios call on the client side and no error messages appear.

My client:

```
submitFile = () => {
    var formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('image', this.state.file, 'tmp_name');//this.state.file is not correct format compared to postman constructed
    axios.post('http://localhost:3000/upload', formData).then(function(response) {
      console.log(response);
    });
  }
```

My server:

```
  server.post('/upload', async (req, res, next) => {
    const upload = multer({ storage }).single('image')
    upload(req, res, function(err) {
      if (err) {
        return res.send(err)
      }
      const path = req.file.path
      cloudinary.uploader.upload(
        path,
        { public_id: `${filename()}` },
        async function(err, image) {
          if (err) return res.send(err)
          console.log('file uploaded to Cloudinary')
          // remove file from server
          const fs = require('fs')
          fs.unlinkSync(path)
        }
      ).then(result => {res.send(result)})
    })
```

Again I want to just be able to view the response and save it but everything after then .then doesn't execute.

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove bracket in then of server code

```
server.post('/upload', async (req, res, next) => {
    /* upload code*/
      ).then(result => res.send(result))
    })
```

OR 
 Add return in then of server code

```
server.post('/upload', async (req, res, next) => {
    /*upload code*/
          ).then(result => { return res.send(result)})
        })
```

Comment: Sorry I reread my question and saw that it was ambiguous as to which .then block I was referring to. I was trying to log the response to console in the front end code to make sure that I was receiving the correct url to save to database but it doesn't appear to run. So to clarify the problem that I'm trying to figure out is in the axios.post line.